# How to set a reader-writer lock for a specific segment of code?

Tags: c#, readerwriterlockslim

I need to lock a specific section of my code and the problem is as follows:

I must allow multiple read threads and single write thread to the section something like:

```
get readlock()
{
if(s==1)
  get writelock()

or else 
   continue with read lock()
}
```

Comment: I added the missing C# tag for you

Comment: Upgrading a lock from reader to writer is covered in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.7.2).